# Ошибка Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error: PreflightMissingAllowOriginHeader

Tags: javascript, http, https, cors

Работаю с API VK. Пробую отправить запрос на получение данных, но выдает данную ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
const redirectUri = 'https://dimonnikolaev.github.io/vkApp/';
const display = 'popup';
const scope = 'friends,notify';
const response_type = 'token';
const state = 'okay';
const revoke = '1';

const url = `https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&display=${display}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scope}&response_type=${response_type}&v=5.130&state=${state}`;

const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://dimonnikolaev.github.io/vkApp/');
    req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    req.send();
    req.onload = function () {
        const json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        console.log(json);
    };
});

(async function () {
    // let success = await promise.then((date) => date);
    // let error = await promise.catch((error) => error);

    console.log(await promise.catch((error) => error));
})();
```

*clientId не оставил за кулисами*

Comment: Вы отправляете бессмысленные заголовки. Эти заголовки должен отправлять сервер в ответ на запрос. Из браузера они не имеют смысла.

Comment: Вы предлагаете перестать отправлять заголовки или поменять их ? При первом варианте выходит следующая ошибка: missing allow origin header

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но вроде это апи вообще-то не предназначено для работы из браузера. Для браузера у них есть JavaScript SDK